# Customer Weekly logins analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql

Maybe someone could help?

I'm using PostgreSQL, and I'm trying to create a Cohort analysis so I can track user logins. I’m not an SQL guru myself, but I’ve found many examples, but many of them customized to MySQL or outdated. I've been stuck at this point for a couple of days, thank you.

Cohort - customers who registered in one week (e.g. week 19)

Desired results:

Let me explain... We have one row which is Cohort, the first week is the count of registered users, the next week shows how many of the registered users logged in, and the third week is also showing how many of the users have logged in after the second week, and it keeps continuing.

2 tables are used: `users_user`, `users_logins`.

```
users_user fields: | id | last_login | date_joined |
users_logins fields: | created_at | user_id |
```

Required table:

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the numbers in you desired result? What are the examples that you found? In which way are they outdated? In which way are they specific to MySQL?

Comment: Most of the examples are for MySQL or just not working. What I need is to make a table that would show how many users registered in week 0 for example. and how many of them later logged in at week 1. It's just business logic to see how many users use the app.
https://www.holistics.io/blog/calculate-cohort-retention-analysis-with-sql/
https://medium.com/cheerz-engineering/simple-cohort-analysis-with-sql-4840e6bf31da
https://blog.statsbot.co/customer-retention-analysis-93af9daee46b


https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-revenue-cohort-analysis-in-sql-and-python-9eeecd4c731a

Comment: Sample data, desired results, explanation of the numbers, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  Nothing in your tables is called "week" so the question is rather confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this clear?

Comment: Is the list of columns variable, or fixed?  What do they mean, anyway -- week 1 is  the number of users who registered in this cohort, who logged in any time within one week later?

Comment: @MikeB what do you mean by fixed? As I'm really green in SQL I don't really know, I think it doesn't matter. Week 1 is the number of users who registered and in week 2 is the number of users that have logged in any time within one week later, yes.. And we continue this checking principal at other weeks.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DATE_PART('week', date_joined),
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN (DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined) <= 1*7) THEN 1 
        ELSE NULL))
    END
) AS week_1,
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN (DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined) <= 2*7) THEN 1 
        ELSE NULL))
    END
) AS week_2,
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN (DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined) <= 3*7) THEN 1 
        ELSE NULL))
    END
) AS week_3,
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN (DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined) <= 4*7) THEN 1 
        ELSE NULL))
    END
) AS week_4
from users_user
group by DATE_PART('week', date_joined)
```

Notes:

- Expand for as many columns as you want.
- You probably also want to add a year column to the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` so it doesn't break for time spans greater than a year.
- I wrote this without a database, so it contains bugs and typos, but I hope the basic idea comes across.

Comment: how would you write in postgreSQL? Because function `DATEDIFF` does not exist

Comment: Ooops, updated the query. I misread http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Comment: `DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined)` can be simplified to `last_login::date - date_joined::date` if both columns are defined as `timestamp`  or `last_login - date_joined` if both columns are defined as `date`

Comment: syntax error at or near "when" LINE 4: ... WHEN (DATE_PART('day', last_login - date_joined) when <= 1*... ^

Comment: There were some superfluous `when`. I updated the code. Anyway my last point still applies: "I wrote this without a database, so it contains bugs and typos, but I hope the basic idea comes across."